# How to make toctree link refer to the separate file like it refers to the subsections

Tags: python-sphinx, sidebar, restructuredtext, read-the-docs, toctree

#### Structure

The following structure of the project:

- `index.rst`

  ```
  MyProject
  =========

  Contents:

  .. toctree::

     group1
  ```
- `group1.rst`

  ```
  Group1
  ------

  Subgroup1
  =========

  Subgroup1 contents

  Subgroup2
  =========

  Subgroup2 contents
  ```

Rendered to (after clicking on `Group1` -> `Subgroup2`):

[image: clicked-on-subsection]

As you can see it opens the `Group1` page and linked to `Subgroup2` section.

#### Want

I want to have the same on the left side (`Group1` openned and `Subgroup2` choosed) but on the right side I want to see only `Subgroup2` page (page without `Subgroup1` content).

I.e. have file `group1/subgroup1.rst`:

```
Subgroup2
=========

Subgroup2 contents
```

Rendered to:

[image: want]

How it can be achieved? This is a simple example with the depth 2, what about depth 3-4?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to have a file per page of content. Sphinx doesn't break files into multiple pages.

What works for me is creating `toctree` directives that reference files containing sub-`toctree` directives. I like to create the sub-groups in directories, but you could do this within one directory.

`index.rst`:

```
MyProject
=========

Contents:

.. toctree::

   group1/index
```

`group1/index.rst`:

```
Group1
======

.. toctree::

   subgroup1
   subgroup2
```

`group1/subgroup1.rst`:

```
Subgroup1
=========

Subgroup1 contents
```

`group1/subgroup2.rst`:

```
Subgroup2
=========

Subgroup2 contents
```